# Is there a way to force a jdbc connection to use TCP?

Tags: sql-server-2005, jdbc, tcp, connection-string, protocols

In a normal SQL Server 2005 connection string, it's possible to specify the desired protocol in the following format:

```
Data Source=tcp:myServerAddress;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Is there a way to do something similar in a JDBC connection string to SQL Server?

**Edit:**

My JDBC Connection String looks like this:

```
JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
Provider=Mondrian;Jdbc=
    'jdbc:sqlserver://myServerAddress;
    instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;
    databaseName=myDataBase;integratedSecurity=true;';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting the actual IP address for the server name seems to do the trick.